# Nodemon app crashed - when i send a post request from restEasy chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-chrome, express

I want to add data to my mongodb collection collection name is 'post' ,
here is my server.js code

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());  

Post = require('./www/js/models/post.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/BlogDB'); //connect to mongoose
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.post('/api/post',function (req, res) {
    var post = req.body;
    Post.addPost(post,function (error, post) {
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        res.json(post);
    })
});
```

this is my post schema-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/// Post schema
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, {collection: 'post'});

var Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
//add post
module.exports.addPost = function (post, callback) {
    Post.create(post,callback);
};
```

when i send post request from RestEasy chrome extension then throw this error msg

```
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 ValidationError: Post validation failed
    at MongooseError.ValidationError (F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:23:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1501:32)
    at F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1377:17
    at validate (F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:705:7)
    at F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:742:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:710:19)
    at F:\Project\Private\Blog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1375:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Mongoose tells you that the data you're inserting in Mongo is not valid as it does not satisfy the schema you built. So check carefully what you're inserting.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh tnq bro, it's work

Comment: should I post this as the answer?

Comment: yes u can post as answer

Comment: Tip: don't use `throw` in async callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValidationError: Post validation failed

Mongoose tells you that the data you're inserting in Mongo is not valid as it does not satisfy the schema you built. So check carefully what you're inserting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems schema validation error for post data JSON from Mongoose.,

```
{
    "title": "Javascript",
    "description": "Javascript story",
    "author": "Karthikeyan.A",
    "date:: "Tue Apr 04 2017 13:56:23 GMT+0530 (IST)"
}
```